# How do I install the window-list Gnome shell extension in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I installed Gnome-shell on my work PC running on Ubuntu 16.04 and it has the window-list extension by default. I upgraded it to 18.04 and the window-list extension is still there.

But on my freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my home PC, I can't find it via `apt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension you are looking for is now grouped with all "official" gnome shell extensions in the package `gnome-shell-extensions`. Thus, install that package. After that, extensions including `Window list` and `Applications menu` will be available.

Of course, you can also find the extension on the Gnome Shell extensions website, but then you venture out of the standard software repository, which is not officially supported by the Ubuntu developers.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. The only extra step that I did was to reboot my PC, as the extensions did not load right away on the Tweaks tool. (Or perhaps logging out would have sufficed?)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/ .
2. Install extension (add-on) for your browser.
3. Refresh page in browser. If all ok with browser add-on (you don't have to see the suggestion to install browser add-on anymore), turn window-list extension trigger to **On**. And now you can install another extension from https://extensions.gnome.org/ using this browser simple switch them on html page to On state.

And i recommend install GNOME Tweak Tool to manage installed extensions:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually found that page beforehand, but I wanted to install it via apt as much as possible. @vanadium's response worked for me!